# How to get the ip address from the gamer?

Tags: c#

I have an android game with one player against the other , how to get the ip address to send the positions ?

Comment: What framework are you using? Is it player vs player using direct connection, or do you have a server that connects them?

Comment: I want direct connection

Comment: How do you identify which player's IP you want to get?

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of a tricky thing. You will certainly need a master server, which manages the players which are online and their IP's to match players.
You can first search for another player, e.g. by name or matchmaking. How you do that entirely depends on how you store and manage the players on your master server.

One simple option would be to use the [Google Multiplayer API](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer). It handles matching, invitations and connection stuff for you, you only have to implement the game logic and  network logic, but the connection and initiation is handled for you. This would be the most straightforward and simplest solution. I don't know which framework you are using, since you specified this to be a C# question, so it may be difficult to integrate the Google API to your project.

The second possibility is to use your own Master Server. This is significantly more complicated than using the Google API. Additionally, if you want to use a direct connection to the other player, the problem arises that, unless you are in the same network, most players will sit behind a router or are in a mobile network. It is very complicated to connect to a device behind a firewall or in a public network, if you cannot assume certain ports to be opened. Either you route your connection completely to your own servers, or you can try something like a [NAT Punchthrough](https://keithjohnston.wordpress.com/2014/02/17/nat-punch-through-for-multiplayer-games/). Here again, the Google API will handle that for you.